# Regex to match google map lat long

Tags: javascript, regex, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google map and i need to update map using lat long and to verify that some doesn't put invalid data i want a regex which can test entered lat long

But now when i see there are three type of lat long as described here

[Google Map Lat Long Search](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/18539?hl=en)

I made a regex for `Decimal degrees (DDD)` which is following

```
^([-+]?\d{1,2}([.]\d+)?),\s*([-+]?\d{1,3}([.]\d+)?)$
```

But this regex doesn't fulfill

```
Degrees, minutes and seconds (DMS): 41° 24' 12.1674", 2° 10' 26.508"
```

AND

```
Degrees and decimal minutes (DMM): 41 24.2028, 2 10.4418
```

So in simple i need regex to verify all these three types

Comment: Just to clarify - do you expect users to enter one of these strings? Would they include the degree , minute, second signs? And do you not know which of these they are entering? How do you expect people with N/S and E/W: will they use negative numbers, or will they use letters? Before or after the number?

Comment: Why do you need to do it in one regex instead of three ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an OR operator `|`

`^` anchor beginning
`(?:` start a non-capturing group
`([-+]?\d{1,2}([.]\d+)?),\s*([-+]?\d{1,3}([.]\d+)?)` Your current regex.
`|` OR
Make one for degrees & minutes & seconds
`|` OR
Make one for degrees and decimal minutes
`)` end non-capturing group
`$` anchor end

Let me know if you have more questions on this.